# C++: If an exception is thrown, are objects that go out of scope destroyed?

Tags: c++, exception, visual-studio-2008, scope, throw

Normally it would be destructed upon the scope ending.. I could see issues occurring if exceptions were thrown though.

Comment: Just have a look-see at the assembly listing that the compiler can generate with /FAs.  You can't miss the exception filters that ensure that they are destroyed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.

C++ Standard n3337

### 15 Exception handling

**§** 15.2 Constructors and destructors

> 1) As control passes from a throw-expression to a handler, destructors
>   are invoked for **all automatic objects constructed since the try block
>   was entered**. The automatic objects are destroyed in the reverse order
>   of the completion of their construction.
>
> 2) An object of any storage duration whose initialization or
>   destruction is terminated by an exception will have destructors
>   executed for **all** of its **fully constructed subobjects** (excluding the
>   variant members of a union-like class), that is, for subobjects for
>   which the principal constructor (12.6.2) has completed execution and
>   the destructor has not yet begun execution. Similarly, if the
>   non-delegating constructor for an object has completed execution and a
>   delegating constructor for that object exits with an exception, the
>   object’s destructor will be invoked. If the object was allocated in a
>   new-expression, the matching deallocation function (3.7.4.2, 5.3.4,
>   12.5), if any, is called to free the storage occupied by the object.
>
> 3) The process of calling destructors for automatic objects
>   constructed on the path from a try block to a throw-expression is
>   called “stack unwinding.” If a destructor called during stack
>   unwinding exits with an exception, std::terminate is called (15.5.1).
>   [ Note: So destructors should generally catch exceptions and not let
>   them propagate out of the destructor. — end note ]

example:

```
SomeClass c;              // declared before try{} so it is
                          // still valid in catch{} block
try {
    SomeClass t;
    throw;
} catch( ...) {
    // t destroyed
    // c valid
}
```

Comment: Let's say `class A` has a mutex member variable. Thread T1 comes into `A::doSomething()` which locks the mutex using a stack created lock object. After locking the mutex an exception is thrown which is NOT caught. Does the mutex ever get unlocked?

Comment: What if there is no `catch` block?

Answer (score 3):

Yes any scope bound variables will be destroyed.

```
void work()
{
     Foo a;
     Foo* b = new Foo;
     // ... later

     // exception thrown

     delete b;
}
```

In this example `a`'s destructor would be called when the exception was thrown as the stack unwound, but the memory pointed to by `b` would be leaked since it would never reach the `delete` call. This is one of the many reasons why RAII is so helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When you leave a scope (whether normally or via exception) objects local to that scope are destroyed. This is the basic fact that makes RAII/SBRM work.